# RSS and cached values

Tags: rss

How can I (or is it possible) to remove some blog posts out of a feed such as Google Feedburner? I have removed some from my blog but obviously looks like they are cached somehow. I just don't want some of the blog posts to be able to be read through anyone who subscribes...I don't want them to see those posts that I removed in the future in the feed itself.

Am I asking the impossible here? I don't know how RSS works in terms of cache/history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to remove the item from the original feed from your site. Either delete it or hide it, whatever it takes to have it no longer show in the RSS that is generated directly from your site.

Then you can either:

- [Ping Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/ping) so that it can refresh their copy of your feed
- [Resync the feed](http://gulati.info/2009/11/deleting-a-feedburner-feed-item/) by going to the *Troubleshootize* tab in Feedburner and clicking the **Resync Now** button toward the bottom of the page

This only will work for those who have not already downloaded a copy of the feed.

If they have, you can't delete their copy and will only be able to prevent future readers of the feed from seeing the items you wanted deleted.

Comment: yea I've done that resync and stuff..did not help.

Comment: If this answer didn't help, unaccept it and wait for someone to offer something better. The checkmark will slow down others who will see it and think your problem is solved. @cof